# numpy: how to select rows based on a bunch of criteria

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

How can I fetch the rows for which the second column equals to 4 or 6?

```
a = np.array(np.mat('1 2; 3 4; 5 6; 7 4'))
b = [4,6]
```

Apparently, this does not work:

```
c = a[a[:,1] in b]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `itertools.ifilter` :

```
from itertools import ifilter
c = np.array([ e for e in ifilter(lambda x: x[1] in b, a) ])
>> array([[3,4],
          [5,6],
          [7,4]])
```

Comment: This is very slow for large arrays. When working with NumPy arrays, vectorized idioms are to be preferred.

Comment: what is telling you OP is using large arrays ? I use extensively Numpy without working on Big Data.

Answer (score 10):

The numpythonic way of doing this would be to use [`in1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html), something like:

```
a[np.in1d(a[:, 1], b)]
```

Answer (score 2):

[x for x in a if x[1] in (4,6,)] should do it for the case you've mentioned.

Edit: As @georgesl suggests, "an ideal way" is to use an iterator right while constructing the array rather than using the numpy.mat method on the string.

Comment: Same objection as to georgesl's answer: this is unnecessarily slow because it doesn't use NumPy's vectorized operations.

Comment: larsmans As much as it is a valid concern on not being optimized for such operations, it still is valid as @georgesl's comment goes. OP hasn't explicitly made any indication about using large arrays.

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
check = np.logical_or(a[:,1]==4, a[:,1]==6)
c = a[check,:]
```

You can also use `|` for the logical operator `or`:

```
check = (a[:,1]==4) | (a[:,1]==6)
```